# Event Registration - Pending (Pay Later) - Cannot add payment

Tags: civievent, payment

Example of issue:

Website user registers for event - chooses pay later option.

User makes payment via cash or other method at event.

Site administrator tries to change status to Completed and record payment.

Error: Sorry but we are not able to provide this at the moment.

Replicated in Drupal DMaster

Via log:

```
[info] $backTrace = #0 /home/columbiaccs/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(381): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace("backTrace", TRUE)
#1 /home/columbiaccs/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contribute/Form/AdditionalPayment.php(121): CRM_Core_Error::fatal("No payment information found for this record")
#2 /home/columbiaccs/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Form.php(585): CRM_Contribute_Form_AdditionalPayment->preProcess()
#3 /home/columbiaccs/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/QuickForm/Action/Display.php(92): CRM_Core_Form->buildForm()
#4 /home/columbiaccs/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Controller.php(203): CRM_Core_QuickForm_Action_Display->perform(Object(CRM_Contribute_Form_AdditionalPayment), "display")
#5 /home/columbiaccs/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Page.php(103): HTML_QuickForm_Controller->handle(Object(CRM_Contribute_Form_AdditionalPayment), "display")
#6 /home/columbiaccs/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Controller.php(351): HTML_QuickForm_Page->handle("display")
#7 /home/columbiaccs/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Wrapper.php(113): CRM_Core_Controller->run()
#8 /home/columbiaccs/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(282): CRM_Utils_Wrapper->run("CRM_Contribute_Form_AdditionalPayment", "New Payment", (Array:0))
#9 /home/columbiaccs/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(84): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:16))
#10 /home/columbiaccs/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(52): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:2))
#11 /home/columbiaccs/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/drupal/civicrm.module(445): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:2))
#12 /home/columbiaccs/www/www/includes/menu.inc(527): civicrm_invoke("payment")
#13 /home/columbiaccs/www/www/index.php(21): menu_execute_active_handler()
#14 {main}
```

and

```
 [info] $Fatal Error Details = Array
(
    [message] => No payment information found for this record
    [code] => 
)
```

Comment: What message do you get in the ConfigAndLog file? (Use Alan Dixon’s handy https://civicrm.org/extensions/civicrm-log-viewer to view your ConfigAndLog via the GUI)

Comment: Make sure you record payment before changing the status to completed. As when you submit the record payment form, it should automatically set the status to correct value without you doing it manually.

Comment: @KarinG-SemperIT added log files.

Comment: @jitendra-fuzion - yes we are doing that.

Comment: you say you've replicated on dmaster. Can you list down the steps pls?